# Default path of database in a bootstrap website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Boss just gave me a website of his friend so the developer that build it was fired and i need to access the data base to change things.

The Website is developed using Bootstrap and I never used it Before where do I find the definition of the database connection help please.

Comment: Going once through [this section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) is guaranteed to drastically improve your chances at getting your question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere.

Bootstrap is a collection of CSS and (client-side) JavaScript.

It isn't a traditional, server-side MVC framework (or anything else that would fulfil a similar role) and doesn't do anything that would involve a database.

Bootstrap might be used in the output of a View from such a framework, but that's handled at a different level in the codebase.

Comment: i thought so but the config.php file is connecting me to a database  that when i change values in it nothing changes in the page so i thought maybe he's using another database any suggestions of how to find it ?

Comment: @OussemaM'zoughi — `config.php` (or any other PHP) has nothing to do with Bootstrap. I refer you back to the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Oussema, from your comments it is clear that you lack some very basic, yet essential knowledge about web technology. If your main concern is not to lose your job, you are far more likely to lose it if you continue without asking for professional help. You will mess that website up. It's not a matter of *if*, but of *how soon*. In your position it would be a lot better to tell your boss. *I don't know much about this. I don't want to mess it up*.

Comment: Is this a Wordpress site that is just using the bootstrap Framework perchance?